# Eclipse cannot open java me perspective

Tags: eclipse, java-me

I'd like to learn java me. I've gone to the following site to download what is needed. My Eclipse version is [Juno](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javame/javamobile/download/sdk/index.html).

I've done the following:

```
Eclipse Juno
The Oracle Java ME SDK requires the MTJ toolkit, but it is not bundled with Juno and it must be installed manually. Therefore, install MTJ toolkit first.

    Go to Help > Install New Software.
    In the "Work with" field, enter this URL: http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo
    Click Add. When the plugins are discovered, open the Mobile and Device Development Tools hierarchy and check Mobile Tools for Java Examples, Mobile Tools for Java SDK, and Mobile Tools for Java Examples. Click Next. On the installation screen select all plugins and click Finish.
    A Juno plugin named org.eclipse.jetty.server_(version).jar conflicts with the MTJ libraries when the plugin version is higher than 6. If it is you must prevent it from loading by changing its name so the Jar file is not parsed. For example, change it to: org.eclipse.jetty.server.old
    To open the device selector, select Window > Open Perspective > Other and select Java ME.
```

The MTJ is installed along with the 3 packages that also need to be installed:

- Mobile Tools for Java Examples
- Mobile Tools for Java SDK
- Mobile Tools
  for Java Examples

When I choose: `Window` > `Open Perspective` > `Other` 
there is no Java ME option. Does anyone know why that option is not shown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know exactly why, but `MTJ` does not run with [`Juno`](http://www.eclipse.org/juno/). If you like `Eclipse` try it with [`Indigo`](http://www.eclipse.org/indigo/).
Have you considered using [`NetBeans`](http://netbeans.org/downloads/)?

Comment: Hi, yes i downloaded Indigo last night and it works fine. I use indigo for learning java ME stuff then Juno for Android. Thanks